# Elegant way of repeating statements

Tags: python, if-statement

```
def foo():
        global interupsi
        distance = 50  
        while distance>0:
                pyautogui.drag(distance, 0, duration=0.5)   # move right
                if interupsi:
                        break
                distance -= 5
                pyautogui.drag(0, distance, duration=0.5)   # move down
                if interupsi:
                        break
                pyautogui.drag(-distance, 0, duration=0.5)  # move left
                if interupsi:
                        break
                distance -= 5
                pyautogui.drag(0, -distance, duration=0.5)  # move up
                if interupsi:
                        break
```

Any there way to make each statement efficient?
if statements can stored to array or list, it will be easier just do with iterration.
I expect like this

```
statement_list=[statement1,statement2,statement3,statement4]

def foo():
        global interupsi
        distance = 50  
        while distance>0:
                for statements in statement_list
                        statements()
                        if interupsi:
                                break
```

So the statements saved to list named `statement_list` and it called with iteration so it will be efficient, I don't need copy paste `if interrupsi:` repeatedly.

**Note**: the `interupsi` variable may be changed whenever.

Comment: `pyautogui.drag` can change the `interupsi` value ? In second code it should be `statements()` to actuall call the method

Comment: @azro interupsi value is changed by ```keyboard``` module so it's another topic. it will changed if i pressed 'q' then the interupsi will set to ```True```

Comment: Functions are objects that can be stored in lists, not statements. That wouldn't solve your problem though because distance is a local variable and wouldn't be able to be modified in the functions unless it's returned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume that you still want the `break` to exit the `while` loop, so you need to either handle that properly or use something other than an inner loop. Here I'll cycle across some statements stored earlier for execution and check the distance along with `interupsi`. I'm not sure I would describe this as elegant, however.

```py
from itertools import cycle

actions = [
'''pyautogui.drag(distance[0], 0, duration=0.5)
''',
'''distance[0]-= 5
pyautogui.drag(0, distance[0], duration=0.5)
''',
'''pyautogui.drag(-distance[0], 0, duration=0.5)
''',
'''distance[0]-= 5
pyautogui.drag(0, -distance[0], duration=0.5)
''',
'''time.sleep(0.1)
''' ]

def foo():
    global interupsi
    distance = [50] 
    for action in cycle(actions):
        exec(action)
        if interupsi or distance[0] <= 0:
            break
```

One wrinkle was that I had to make distance an element in a list, so that the routine and the exec'd commands were acting on the same item.

Answer (score 2):

You can store the directions in a list of vectors

```
directions = [(1,0), (0, 1), (-1,0), (0,-1)]
distance = 50  
while distance>0 and not interupsi:
    for i, vector in enumerate(directions):
        pyautogui.drag(distance*vector[0], distance*vector[1], duration=0.5)
        if interupsi:
            break
        if i in {0,2}:  # or check if even 
            distance -= 5
```

Comment: i was thinking about save the directions to list instead of statement, actually i wanted to do it even before i ask this but im thinking im just lucky i can manipulate direction instead statement ```only for this case```. So this answer is not general answer.

Comment: @MuhammadIkhwanPerwira If this isn't a general answer it is because you didn't ask a general question. It seems odd to complain about an answer that succeeds in answering the question that you actually asked, just because it doesn't answer a question that you didn't ask.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. This reduces the duplicate code you asked for